# How do I apply a timecode and then I speed up x4 a video with ffmpeg without losing quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, timecode

I'm trying to create a .bat file for ffmpeg that:

- Applies a timecode overlay (e.g. 00:17:23:02)
- Speeds up the video x4 (but AFTER the timecode is applied)
- Doesn't "touch" the quality of the original video

---

This is what I got:

`for %%a in ("*.avi") do (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=5:text='Real \time\:':fontsize=46:fontcolor=white:x=30:y=30: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -f avi "%%~na_with-time.avi"
)`

---

It works but I can't speed up x4 the video and it also losses a lot of the quality (very pixelated when moving around in the video)

This is what code I could use to speed up x4 the video but I can't get it in the code above (to work):
`"setpts=0.25*PTS"`

Also this is the quality:

How the video looks before:
[image]

After conversion with the ffmpeg .bat code above:
[image]

Is there a way to speed-up the video x4 (but with the normal time timecode) and also don't change the quality of the exported video)?

Also is there a way to make the black box behind the timecode a bit bigger (5 pixels in all directions: left, up, right, down)? Or maybe a stroke effect to the text instead of the black box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for %%a in ("*.avi") do (
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=5:text='Real \time\:':fontsize=46:fontcolor=white:x=30:y=30:box=1:boxcolor=0x00000000@1:boxborderw=5,setpts=0.25*PTS" -c:v libx264 -f avi "%%~na_with-time.avi"
)
```

Added `boxborderw=5` for border width.

Added setpts after the drawtext.

Added encoder explicitly `-c:v libx264` - its default settings should produce good images. You can also stick with the default encoder (mpeg4) and just add `-q:v 5` for decent quality - the default of 200 kbps is too low.

---

For a custom timecode string, remove `timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=5`

and change `text` to

`text='Real \time\: %{eif\:trunc(t/3600)\:d\:2}h %{eif\:trunc(mod(t/60\,60))\:d\:2}m %{eif\:trunc(mod(t\,60))\:d\:2}s'`

Comment: Thank you!
Is there a way to replace the 
Real time:00:06:31:04 
with
Real time: 00h 06m 31s
(so there is a space after time:, no more : and frames (latests digits) are removed)?

Comment: Also, is possible to center the timecode (horizontally) without checking how wide is the video (so I don't use 1920/2 = 960). Maybe something like 50% (similar to HTML/CSS 50%)?

Comment: For horizontally centering, add `x='(W-tw)/2'`. A custom string can be done but it's a bit involved so I'll add it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested the code and there's an issue with the text size of the timecode, if the video is very big (2K/4K), the timecode is very small.
Is there a way to make the timecode 20% of the width of the video?

Comment: Not directly. Add `fontsize=H/10` where H is video height. Test and see what expression results in the required footprint.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to fix this problem: Sometimes the rendered/converted video is longer than the actual time (so in this screenshot it says that it's 51 minutes long but actually it's 7:59 minutes, it can't got past 7:59 mins in this player): https://i.imgur.com/MozuyV4.png

Comment: That sounds like a corrupt AVI. Can C4D save to a different format?

Comment: I'm not recording with/saving from Cinema 4D. I'm recording using Bandicam.